# Does SKLearn have any methods for visualizing the data in a NearestNeighbors model?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have a trained NearestNeighbors model with 76 dimension of data. It returns meaningful predictions which I can then use to output charts or tables of data.

I am looking for ways to visualize this model & its data in order to illustrate its utility and how it works to users.

I noticed SKLearn documentation has some charts for visualizing k-means/KNN - but they don't go into details on how these charts were created. I am wondering if there are convenient utility methods somewhere for visualizing your model & data - even if that visualization involves reduction in dimensionality to the point that it is no longer all that useful.

My users like pictures & charts.

Comment: can you link those charts form the sklearn docs?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-classification-py

Comment: That link shows you how to do it for 2D data (two features). The problem is that you have 76 dimensions. You could try making projections of some combinations of the most important features onto 2D. Principal component analysis might help you to reduce the number of dimensions considerably, but 76 is a very high starting point...

Comment: @JayMody https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html and others from the https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html page. Issue is these are for classification, whereas I'm doing neighbor search.

Comment: @SimonR thanks for the response. I was looking at skl's neighbor PCA but as you mention - if the problem statement is really "how do I display 76-dimensional distance in a 2-dimensional space" the correct answer might be "why bother." Just wondering if SKL authors have come up with a creative solution already